# Combinations probability question leads to two different answers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I'm confused why my two approaches are leading to different answers.

Assume you have an audience of size A and some ad impressions to serve them denoted B. Assignment is independent for each ad. **ETA**: Each ad is served to one person only, and each person may get several ads. Assume $B \geq A$.

**Question:** What's the probability that every audience member will be served at least one ad impression? The case where the number of impressions is smaller than the number of audience members is trivial and I'm ignoring it.

This is how I tried to solve it:

P(every person has at least 1 impression) = 1 - P(someone has no impression)

To start,

P(someone has no impression) = $(1-\frac{1}{A})^B$

This comes from using the binomial distribution. Success is defined as a person getting served an ad, which, given they're served independently, is $\frac{1}{A}$. Failure, or not getting served an ad, is $(1-\frac{1}{A})$. Failure for all B ads is then $(1-\frac{1}{A})^B$

So then:

P(every person has at least 1 impression) = $1 -  (1-\frac{1}{A})^B$

Now try to solve with a toy example, assuming A = 2 and B = 3.

This means there are $A^B = 2^3 = 8$ ways that 3 ads can be served to 2 people. Of the 8 combinations, 2 combinations serve ads to a single person.

So P(every person has at least 1 impression) = $\frac{6}{8}$ when counting combinations.

But plugging in A=2 and B=3 in the prior equation gets you:

P(every person has at least 1 impression) = $1 -  (1-\frac{1}{A})^B = 1 - (1-\frac{1}{2})^3 = \frac{7}{8}$

**I'm confused how counting combinations leads to $\frac{6}{8}$, but the formula leads to $\frac{7}{8}$. Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: Even more. There's no case in example where not both of surveyed are not impressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(1-\frac1A)^B$ is not the probability that someone will get no impression. It is the probability that a fixed particular person will get no impression.

Probability that every person gets at least one impression is $\frac{S(B, A)\cdot A!}{A^B}$, where $S(n,k)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Or you could calculate it using [the inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

So if $A=2,$ $B=3$, you indeed get $6/8$.

**Edit**

Here is how you can use the inclusion-exclusion reasoning.

There are $A^B$ ways to distribute the impressions. We then subtract the cases when each particular person didn’t get an impression. The answer becomes $A^B - \binom{A}1\cdot (A-1)^B$.

You have to add the cases when two persons didn’t get an impression. There are $\binom{A}2\cdot (A-2)^B$ of them. And so on. In the end, you get the answer

$$\frac{A^B - \binom{A}1\cdot (A-1)^B + \binom{A}2\cdot (A-2)^B + …}{A^B}=$$

$$= \frac{ \sum_{i=0}^A (-1)^{i}\binom{A}{i} (A-i)^B}{A^B}=$$

$$= \frac{ \sum_{i=0}^A (-1)^{A-i}\binom{A}{i} i^B}{A^B}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use the exclusion-inclusion principle to create a formula for arbitrary A and B?

Comment: @Wildcat09 I edited my answer to include this reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your problem is not well-defined. Here are a couple of ambiguities, for example.

1. Does each ad have to be served to exactly 1 person in the audience?
2. Can one person be served multiple ads?

If we assume the answer to both of these questions is yes, then your second approach is correct. The first has errors in it.

---

The probability that an individual in the audience is served a particular ad is $\dfrac{1}{A}$. So the probability that they are not served that particular ad is $1 - \dfrac{1}{A}$. And so the probability that an individual is not served any ad is $\left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{A}\right)^B$.

Now if you are following the negation route and want to find the probability that at least one individual is not served any ad, then you will have to account for the different possibilities - exactly one person is not served, exactly 2 people and so on so forth. You could do this is different ways but the binomial distribution (at least in the way you have applied it) is certainly not one of them.

When you consider assigning all the ads to people one by one. The probability that an individual gets an ad is dependent on which ads have already been assigned / not assigned. The the probability of *success* is not the same for each person.

---

It's also important to not that with the assumptions stated above, if  $A > B$, then the answer to your question would be $0$, simply because there are not enough ads to serve to everyone in the audience.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the binomial distribution that would be correct? I figured my approach was incorrect once I did the toy example and counted 6/8, but I can't see how to make the binomial distribution get the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is.